# How to generate table header(multiple) and body dynamically in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I want to generate a table with 3 headers like following:

[image] Table contains 2 type of columns distribution. Static columns (Bug, Development, Story Defects, BA/QA) and dynamic columns e.g "Task", "Story", "Infrastructure" etc (You can see in my JSON).
Dynamic section can have 0, 1, 2....n number of columns names they will always be dynamic.
Then I want to show the data in percentage and days for both static and dynamic columns

My data format:

```
 [
  {
    "Member Name": "Jillian",
    "Bug": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Story Defect": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Development": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "QA/BA": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Improvement": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Task": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "Member Name": "Nasir",
    "Bug": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Story Defect": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Development": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "QA/BA": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Improvement": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    },
    "Task": {
      "totalDaysSpent": 0,
      "percentage": 0
    }
  }
]
```

In JSON response `workLogDistribution.values` are static columns and `workLogDistribution.others` are dynamic columns

I tried to create data format like following, this works for static columns but still I do not know how to create headers dynamically. Need help!

How can I achieve this? Please let me know.

```js
  jsonData: any = [
    {
      Member: "Member q", devPercentage: "10%", devInDays: "2h", qaPercentage: "10%", QAInDays: "2h",
      bugPercentage: "10%", bugInDays: "2h", defectPercentage: "10%", DefectInDays: "2h", timeSpentOnTaskPercentage: "3%", timeSpentOnTaskdays: "2days"
    },
    {
      Member: "Nasir", devPercentage: "10%", devInDays: "2h", qaPercentage: "10%", QAInDays: "2h",
      bugPercentage: "10%", bugInDays: "2h", defectPercentage: "10%", DefectInDays: "2h", timeSpenOnTaskPercentage: "", timeSpentOnTaskdays: "", timeSpentOnInfraPercentage: "4%", timeSpentOnInfradays: "4days"
    }
  ];
  _object = Object;
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let row of jsonData; let i = index">
              <td *ngFor="let objKey of _object.keys(row); let j = index">{{ row[objKey] }} </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You'll receive downvotes because you haven't provided a snippet of what you already tried doing. Just to clarify.

Comment: You need to iterate over your rows with `<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">` then `<td>{{row.name}}</td> <td>{{row.Story.percentage}}</td>` etc.

Comment: @JeremyThille How can I know that, story is the key in response and it can be changed via server. I cannot bind with dynamic value.

Comment: @LppEdd I have updated my question with the solution I tried but as I cant figure out that how is it possible to achieve. I do not have any working solution.

Comment: @Mishi no problem, I have counter-voted now. Will come up with something as soon as I get home from work, if someone-else doesn't before me.

Comment: @LppEdd Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Mishi Can you please add the data format you need to generate the proper table so I can help you transform that array?

Comment: @krishnasapkal I have added my JSON in question.